# How do I compare an epoch time against 24 hours ago in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, time, epoch

I am using MS SQL Server 2005, I have dates stored in epoch time (starting 1970) I need to create a statement that will affect any record that has not been updated in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current datetime into epoch format, use ([via](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Epoch_Date)):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(s,'19700101 05:00:00:000',GETUTCDATE())
```

To get the epoch time for now - 24 hours use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(s,'19700101 05:00:00:000', DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETUTCDATE()))
```

So, you could do:

```
DECLARE @24_hours_ago AS INT
SELECT @24_hours_ago = DATEDIFF(s,'19700101 05:00:00:000', DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETUTCDATE()))

UPDATE table SET col = value WHERE last_updated < @24_hours_ago
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from SQL Server DateTime to Epoch time by calculating the number of seconds that have elapsed since Jan 1, 1970, like this.

`Select DateDiff(Second, '19700101', GetDate())`

To get rows from the last 24 hours....

```
Select Columns
From   Table
Where  EpochColumn Between DateDiff(Second, '19700101', GetDate()) And DateDiff(Second, '19700101, GetDate()-1)
```